# Licensing the Info Worker Demo?

Tags: 2010

Place I'm working has legit enterprise and technet keys for SP 2010 enterprise.  But when I go into CA - the enable enterprise features radio button is checked and greyed out and when I go to enter the farm license that box is greyed out too.

I realise the VMs are doctored to shut down every 2 hours but that's not a problem.  I want to use it as a test/dev/demo enviroment and I'm definitely NOT given the time to just set it all up myself from scratch.

Has anyone done this - is it possible?  Otherwise I guess I'll just have to backup the sites/content dbs every 120 days and fire up another copy :-(

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can and I seem to recall on the download page they state they are not upgradeable like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can "Rearm" the virtual machine a couple of times to reset the expiration clock:

> To "re-arm" the Virtual Machines use the shortcut provided under Start > All Programs > re-arm > Re-arm Windows (restart required).  This will reset the grace period for 10 days.  This can be done twice.

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27417)

There are also details of activating the full trial for the 180 day period, However, the setup guide asks you not to perform this activation unless your 10 day evaluation expires.

I think the issue with it it that it's actually the "Evaluation Edition" of Win2k8, so there is no way to completely activate it.